# Work Item transition is not returned in VSTS with Rest API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

For some reason I cant't get the transitions (next available states) for a work item with a rest call.

I tried exactly what is in the document:
[transitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/work%20item%20transitions/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1)

Here is my REST call:
BASE_URL/_apis/wit/workitemtransitions?ids=14&api-version=4.1-preview.1

The BASE_URL works with other calls, the id 14 could be loaded also, so it exits, but i don't get back any result if i want to get the transitions(Usual Page not found is returned).

What is the problem here?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue for other work items?

Answer (score 0):

Tested on my side and everything works as expected.

Generally if the base url is incorrect you will receive the `Page not found` message. So please double check if you have entered the correct base url... (maybe a typo?)

Another possibility is that no transitions defined for the specific work item type...

Comment: @GáborCsikós Have you resolved the issue? any update?